# Converting Term names with special characters to Term ID's in Views

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a view where I want to use multiple termID's as arguments. I want to use a term name from the url and convert it to a termID. I've managed to do this easily enough and it works with simple 1 word terms or even multiple words by checking the 'Transform dashes in URL to spaces in term name arguments'

I have a few terms that have special characters eg: "news & politics".

Is there any way to have nice URL's (news-politics) and get views to recognise the correct term and convert it to the correct termID? Will I have to urlencode the ampersand? Will that even work?

Edit: You can setup path aliases for single taxonomy terms, but is a problem when you want to use the term name as a second argument in a path with multiple arguments eg:

Say I wanted to filter the view results by %1 News term then %2 News & Politics

/news/news-politics

second term would not be recognised.

Comment: Why you don't use term name as argument ?

Comment: Same issue. The ampersand is missing so drupal cant find the term. I think the only option is to either url encode the ampersand which  SEO are not keen on or maybe storing a path alias for each term in the db. Just wondered if anyone has encountered this before and has a good strategy.

Comment: Well as a short term solution we are going to just replace & with the word and. So News & Politics (news-politics) will be News and Politics (news-and-politics)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) to set up automatic aliases for your taxonomy terms. Pathauto will take care of invalid url characters for you when it creates the automatic aliases. Then in your view use term id as the argument. The path of your view can either be taxonomy/term/% or the autoalias you set up/%

Comment: Thanks Jepedo. That is a great solution for a single taxonomy term. But there is still an issue if you want to use the term as an wildcard argument in a multi argument path. I should have mentioned that in my original post and have now edited it.

Comment: Check this out: [View Argument Handling Code - Using Multiple Taxnomy Term Names as Arguments](http://groups.drupal.org/node/8500).

Answer (score 2):

Due to a long-standing bug in the Views module reported at [Issue #672606: Plus signs, dashes, and forward slashes (+-/) break arguments](http://drupal.org/node/672606) on Drupal.org, it is not possible to use as arguments (or "contextual filters" in more recent parlance) term names that contain certain special characters. A couple of workarounds [are proposed there](http://drupal.org/node/672606#comment-4145956):

1. Use something like [Computed field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) (computed_field) module to create a URL-friendly field value on the term entity that *can* be used as an argument. Just be aware of the (slim?) chance of very similar terms clobbering each other if you aren't careful about uniqueness.
2. Simply use term IDs for the arguments and create path aliases for them using [View Alias](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_alias) (view_alias) module.