# filter with taxonomy-term-alias instead of term-ID?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, 7

I've my view filtered by taxonomy term ID.

http://aelasoca.cat/web/

(in the main menu I've links to taxonomy ID's 3 to 8). How can I filter with the taxonomy term alias instead of it's ID ??

(not sure if it's the same issue as in: [Views, Taxonomy, Block and Context... What am I doing wrong?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3168/views-taxonomy-block-and-context-what-am-i-doing-wrong) )

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Create a new Taxonomy:Term ID contextual filter.
2. Under the form "When the filter value IS in the URL..." select the option "Specify validation criteria".
3. Select "Taxonomy Term" as the validator.
4. Select which of your vocabularies you'd like to use.
5. Under "Filter Value Type" select "Term name converted to term ID".

That should do it. If you have multiple-word taxonomy terms, you should allow the contextual filter to convert dashes in the URL into spaces for the term name. If you have unusual characters in your taxonomy terms, see [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1973/converting-term-names-with-special-characters-to-term-ids-in-views) for tips.

Comment: user812794, you are my hero! This solution on translating term ID to term name just saved me from severe brain damage. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, this also enables making a view a feature, so you can not count on term ID and name match across different sites.

Comment: How do you compose the URL in cases like this?

Comment: @Hawkee the URL should be defined in your View as something like /your-url/%, where % represents the term name that the contextual filter uses to filter the view. So once you've defined that in the View, you could go to /your-url/gouda and see articles dealing with gouda (for a cheesy example).

Comment: Must be the solution for Views 2.x because the option on line 2 is not available in Views 3.x.

Comment: This was originally written for Views 3.x and the same steps are valid as of the date of this comment.