# Using taxonomy terms alias in views contextual filters

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I hope you can help me out with this. I have created a simple view with an argument. I use that argument to filter (contextual filter) the content of the view. I already know I can use that argument as a taxonomy term ID and as a taxonomy term name, which means I can get my view loaded as:

www.myhost.com/myview/12

or

www.myhost.com/myview/termname

Both ways are ok and work fine but the problem I have is that I'd like to use an alias for the term, instead of the termname. Term names I already have on the site have some characters which are not really SEO friendly.

Is there a way to use the taxonomy term alias or any other workaround to get this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Might want to check out this answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3425/filter-with-taxonomy-term-alias-instead-of-term-id and this answer: http://drupal.org/node/1156022. Posted as a comment because I'm working on the same thing myself.

Comment: As RobW says, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3425/filter-with-taxonomy-term-alias-instead-of-term-id looks like the right way to do this

Answer (score 2):

Finally my work around this was as it follows:

1. I created a custom taxonomy vocabulary which has an extra field "human friendly tag".
2. I changed the name of all the taxonomy terms for being seo-friendly (not spanish accents, nor brackets and so forth).
3. I use term name for the internal stuff in my view (term names are part of the url). You can see how to get this [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3425/filter-with-taxonomy-term-alias-instead-of-term-id) as @RobW pointed out.
4. I use the first field (the "human friendly tag") when content is rendered (in the view). I need to use "rewrite results" options when creating the view.

I hope it is clear enough. :-)

Answer (score 0):

install the [path auto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module and configure the alias patterns for the taxonomy terms as you wish

Comment: Thanks for your response, Blackem, but as far as I can see, pathauto doesn't allow me to use the term alias... I forgot to say I am using panels so things get complicated...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [views](https://drupal.org/project/views), [pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) and [taxonomy_display](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display) modules together. The taxonomy_display module lets override the term's page by your custom view and make it accessible by drupal native pathauto alias.

Usually I use this modules for building the catalog for Commerce shops.

PS: make sure read decumentation for taxonomy_display carefully ;). It has settings on /admin/structure/taxonomy/[vocabulery-name]/display page.

Answer (score 0):

You mention above that you are using panels.  In that case you can create another display of your view with a display type of "Content Pane".  Make the contextual filter look for the tid (not name or name converted), and open up the "Argument input" options and select "From context" for TID.

Now add the new display to the term page in Page manager and in it's panel settings set tid value to the tid context from the term being viewed.  That way it should work regardless of the path the term page is being viewed upon.